# Images in Google Image Search link to sitemap.xml

Tags: xml, image, seo, sitemap

When I search for images on my site, many images return the sitemap when clicked, as you can see [here](https://www.google.nl/search?q=flankenschnitt-stuhl+site:schindlersalmeron.com&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn3OG0hqDZAhWRDuwKHcVbAU8Q_AUICigB&biw=2560&bih=1292). The sitemap returns no errors in Google Search Console. Am I doing something wrong, or should I wait (for better indexing)?

I followed these instructions: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: There is probably a code/programming error in the xml. Why should that be off-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I forgot the image namespace, I now use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd 
http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1 
http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1/sitemap-image.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.schindlersalmeron.com/demo</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://www.schindlersalmeron.com/uploads/demo.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:caption>demo</image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

So I changed this:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
```

Into this:

```
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd 
http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1 
http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1/sitemap-image.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

Comment: What exact change made it work as expected? Can you show a before/after so I can see the diff?  I'm also having this problem

Comment: I have added the diff.

Comment: The namespace you were previously using does follow [Google's recommendations](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en). I'm not convinced your changes were the solution. The example you provided still has the image search results linking directly to the sitemap.

Comment: I would like to see/reproduce that. How can I do that? If I go to google image search, and I click on an image I get redirected to the website.

Comment: All non-PDF images point to /sitemap.xml. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/cFNmKB4.jpg). I'm still looking for a solution on this unusual issue.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the content of your XML isn't properly scraped yet (because of earlier errors) and you have to wait...

Comment: It is remarkable that the first result from my site in [Google Images](https://www.google.nl/search?q=flankenschnitt-stuhl&newwindow=1&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-wLK4k6DZAhVBDuwKHSUaAEoQ_AUICigB&biw=2560&bih=1292#imgrc=noOuP9PRpZRH-M:) DOES work. That one is indexed correctly. Seems like the images sitemap XML does not work, but regular indexing does.

Comment: It turned out that I forgot the image namespace. It is solved now.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else experiencing this issue that has the correct XML data in their sitemap - check that google hasn't indexed your sitemap as a standard, human-readable page. This was the case for us, our sitemap was listed as any other page would be and as a result the images really were from that page, so the visit button linking to the sitemap was technically 'correct'.

Comment: And how do you check the sitemap hasn't been indexed as a standard, human-readable page? Did you search `site:example.com/sitemap.xml`?

Comment: Could it be (related to) this issue? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/62978/prevent-xml-sitemaps-from-showing-up-in-google-search-results

Comment: @Joshua - I used the google search console to determine which pages it had indexed - I searched for 'sitemap' and found that 'page' marked as indexed. Interestingly though our sitemap is just at 'www.domain.com/sitemap' not 'www.domain.com/sitemap.xml' because it is an endpoint that generates a sitemap based on our sites very dynamic content, so the lack of file extension could be what made google think it was a page

Comment: @Langynom Did you solve it? If so, how? You shared a diagnostic. I see one site with the same problem and the sitemap is indexed. I'm guessing the way to solve it is with the [Remove URLs Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en) feature in Google Search.

Comment: That was how I solved it yes - I am yet to look into the root cause of the problem as to why it was indexed in the first place